# Is it correct to store Derived class references in mongoengine ReferenceFields?

Tags: django, mongoengine

I want to know whether I can assign a subclass reference to a
referencefield to the constructor of which the base class has been
passed. For example:

```
class Base(Document):
   str1=StringField(max_length=50)

class Derived(Base):
   str2=StringField(max_length=50)

class Container(Document):
    r=ReferenceField(Base)


d=Derived(str1="str1",str2="str2")
c=Container()
c.r=d
```

Is the line c.r=d valid?

Or do I need to use a GenericReferenceField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer at the mongoengine google group. It is valid to do so.

http://groups.google.com/group/mongoengine-users/browse_thread/thread/324c2d58876708fa